# How To Pushing a Docker image to Azure Container Registry using Cake Building?

Tags: cakebuild

I need build a task on Cake building that allow my to push a docker image to Azure Container Registry. Im searching in internet but I not find how to do that... someone had the same problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what are the obstacles?

Comment: Well, I am working on Azure for kubernetes, so, I have my docker images on a Container registry in Azure. The idea is that when I build the docker Image with the Cake task, the next step is pull the imagen into the container registry.
The principal obstacle is that I dont see how to conect cake to the container registry (I guess I will need a PAT) in order to do the push

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I thinks is not the better way to do it, but I have a first iteration:

```
[TaskName("PushDockerImage")]
[TaskDescription("Login on acr and push Docker Image")]
public sealed class PushDockerImageTask : FrostingTask<BuildContext>
{
    public override void Run(BuildContext context)
    {
        var settings = new AzLoginSettings
        {
            Username = context.AzureLogin,
            Password = context.AzurePassword,
        };
        context.Az().Login(settings);
        var acrSettings = new AzAcrLoginSettings
        {
            Arguments = new ProcessArgumentBuilder()
                .Append("--name").AppendQuoted(context.AzureContainerRegistry)
        };
        context.Az().Acr.Login(acrSettings);
        var imageReference = context.DockerImageReference;
        context.DockerPush(imageReference);
    }
}
```

The principal problem here is that I have to give user and password in the command line. I would like do it with a Pat, but I coudnt do it

Answer (score 0):

So, ignoring Cake for the moment, you "want" to follow the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli?tabs=azure-cli

Roughly:

- login
- tag the image
- push the image

Login in mcr can be done by either azure cli, azure PS, or the docker client using it's `login` command.

So, coming back to Cake you'd probably need a combination of

- [DockerLogin](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Docker/DockerAliases/68E06099) with the `server` parameter set to your mcr reqistry
- [DockerTag](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Docker/DockerAliases/81FA81F7) with the tag containing the fully qualified path to your mcr registry
- [DockerPush](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Docker/DockerAliases/6C5FEDE0)

Comment: Thanks for the indications, Nils. Ok, I think I dont need at the moment tag the image, because I named the Image in the build. Y have both task DockerLogin and DockerPush. However, I get errors in the login:
Error response from daemon: Get https://cractapisdev.azurecr.io/v2/: unauthorized: Application not registered with AAD.
I need use my PAT (Personal Access Token ) to do  the login... Im searching how to do it

Comment: Sorry - I've never done mcr. Have you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal ?

Comment: I have checked it, and is imposible for me.... The idea is not dificulrt, I mean, login in azure  with a personal Access token and push inamge to ACR... but I dont find the way.  I tried creating a service as it said on the previous link, but the ps script dont work fo rme